# Inserting Javascript "Widgets" Onto Remote Sites

Tags: javascript, xss

I am wanting to provide a way for users of my web app to add a widget of sorts on their own websites using Javascript. I've been doing some research on how to best accomplish this and it seems XSS is the only real possible way, but it also seems that the major browsers actually block this as a security threat. What alternative can I use? Of course, the user is installing the code snippet themselves and this is all with permission.

The tutorial i've been following is this:
http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/11/21/diy-widgets/

But I don't think requests like this are possible anymore, correct?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with cross-domain imports of JavaScript code.

Comment: I thought I read that chrome and other browsers block it?

Comment: People do that all the time; for example, it's very common to pull libraries like jQuery from a Google URL.

Comment: I think we're talking about slightly different things. The XSS tutorial I was following has special server requests and responses specific to XSS. I guess I could just build the same sort of thing.

Comment: Well the term "XSS" is all about *attacking* websites by exploiting bugs in page templates (etc). It's not really used to refer to legitimate activities.

Comment: Also, if you can't make remote AJAX requests, how would I pull data from the server?

Comment: Remote ajax is possible either via new headers to explicitly allow it, or by using JSONP.

Comment: ...those headers being those defined by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), and the good news is that they have [relatively good browser support](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=cors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution at the moment is the CORS approach. Nicholas Zakas explains it well in his article: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/